# Sonarqube Not Be Served By Caddy

Tags: linux, ubuntu, web-server, tcp

I'm trying to visit a SonarQube installation I have installed behind the Caddy web server. When I visit the site I don't get a response. I've tried proxying 8999(secure) and  9000(unsecure) with Caddy.

#### Caddyfile

```
https://52.176.62.43 {
  tls self_signed
  gzip
  proxy / 127.0.0.1:8999  
}

http://52.176.62.43 {
  tls off
  gzip
  proxy / 127.0.0.1:9000
}
```

#### sonar.properties

```
# Binding IP address. For servers with more than one IP address, this property specifies which
# address will be used for listening on the specified ports.
# By default, ports will be used on all IP addresses associated with the server.
sonar.web.host=127.0.0.1

# Web context. When set, it must start with forward slash (for example /sonarqube).
# The default value is root context (empty value).
#sonar.web.context=
# TCP port for incoming HTTP connections. Default value is 9000.
#sonar.web.port=9000
sonar.web.https.port=8999
```

#### curl

```
curl -I https://52.176.62.43/
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 52.176.62.43 port 443: Operation timed out
```

Comment: Please elaborate what exactly is "don't get a response".

Comment: @TeroKilkanen Chrome says "This site cannot be reached". You can visit yourself at https://52.176.62.43

Comment: This means that either there is nothing listening to port 80 / 443, or that there is a firewall blocking connections.

Comment: @TeroKilkanen This firewall is set to have both 80 and 433 exposed. Caddy is the one listening on those ports.